# What is the button text retrieved through jQuery here?

Tags: php, jquery, html

The php and html are pretty simple:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['liked_or_not']=0;
?>

<button class="photo_like" value="<?php if($_SESSION['liked_or_not']==0){ echo 'Like';} else{ echo 'Unlike';} ?>" ><?php if($_SESSION['liked_or_not']==0){ echo 'Like';} else{ echo 'Unlike';} ?>
```

jQuery snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

        alert("alert one ="+  $('.photo_like').text());


    if($('.photo_like').text()=='Like'){


    alert("alert two ="+  like_text);
    }

    });

</script>
```

The above code gives the ouput as 'alert one =Like' and then after a few invisible line breaks on the alert box a square. How does that square appear there?

And the second alert box does not appear, as the square box is not included in the      `if($('.photo_like').text()=='Like'){` comparison.

Also Chrome console says :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasPort' of undefined

Explanation?

Comment: How many `photo_like` class elements do you have on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should close your button.

```
<button class="photo_like" value="<?php if($_SESSION['liked_or_not']==0){ echo 'Like';} else{ echo 'Unlike';} ?>" ><?php if($_SESSION['liked_or_not']==0){ echo 'Like';} else{ echo 'Unlike';} ?></button>
```

And use ternary operator can make your code more clear.

```
<?php $like_or_not = $_SESSION['liked_or_not']==0 ? 'Like' : 'Unlike'; ?>
<button class="photo_like" value="<?php echo $like_or_not; ?>"><?php echo $like_or_not; ?></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want the value `Like` and `Unlike` the set in into the hidden input box like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="getTxt" value="<?php if($_SESSION['liked_or_not']==0){ echo 'Like';} else{ echo 'Unlike';} ?>" >
```

and use something like this:

```
var getHiddenVal = $('input[name="getTxt"]').val();
// Return the value
```

its far easy with messing the codes.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.photo_like')` can return multiple objects. To be sure it returns only one object use `$('.photo_like:first')`

To get the value of a button i always use val() instead of text().

So your if should be like this: `if($('.photo_like:first').val()=='Like'){}`